# What is a good JVM based web framework for general use?

Tags: clojure, jvm

I am building some software using Clojure as a backend, and I'd like to use a JVM based solution for the front-end.

I am open to any of the frameworks & languages out there.

I know about Compojure / Webjure / Ring, but I feel like there may be more mature options.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JVM languages *other* than Java there's at least:

- [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) (Ruby on the JVM) which runs the popular [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) framework;
- [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and [Lift](http://liftweb.net/);
- [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (Python on the JVM) and [Django](http://wiki.python.org/jython/DjangoOnJython).
- [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) and [Grails](http://www.grails.org/);

Java itself has quite a few frameworks, none of which stands out from the rest yet.  Some contenders include [Java Server Faces](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/), [Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/), [JBoss Seam](http://www.jboss.com/products/seam/), [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html), and [Apache Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/).